# Automatic PL/SQL Webtool kit based application using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, plsql, ui-automation

I am a newbie in Automation testing and have recently started learning selenium.
We have a Oracle PL/SQL Web tool kit based application. The Interface is used in Internet explorer.
I wanted to know if this UI can be automated with Selenium?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely!

Generally speaking it does not really matter, what toolkit you use when testing with Selenium.

We also have a mod_plsql based application and use Selenium for our UI and integration tests.

The important decision is what environment and language to use when writing the tests. We started by using the Python bindings (https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) but now moved to the JavaScript WebDriverJS (https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs) running on NodeJS. The hard think with JavaScript that not only the tests are async but the driver itself as well.

I would start with the language you feel most comfortable with.

... and good luck: it's quite a challenge to write good tests in Selenium!